# Benefit of defining success/failure function instead of using success/!success

Tags: coding-style

I was reading man page of gearman code (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man3/gearman_success.3.html). They are having two functions

```
   bool gearman_success(gearman_return_t rc)
   bool gearman_failed(gearman_return_t rc)
```

And code of those functions look like (libgearman-1.0/return.h):

```
static inline bool gearman_failed(enum gearman_return_t rc)
{
  return rc != GEARMAN_SUCCESS;
}

static inline bool gearman_success(enum gearman_return_t rc)
{
  return rc == GEARMAN_SUCCESS;
}
```

Both function does nearly same thing. One return true and another false. What is the benefit of this code ?

Why not just have 
           !gearman_success

Is there benefit of coding pattern or something , which I am missing here.

Comment: I have no insight into the dev history of Gearman but you'll see similar idiosyncrasies when trying to preserve backwards compatibility.

Comment: @MikeB seems to be the most probable answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code is easier to extend. Suppose you add another value to that `enum`:

`GEARMAN_SUCCESS_BUT_HAD_WARNINGS`

With the implementation you're looking at, all you have to do is adjust both methods. Without it, you'd have to go through every place `GEARMAN_SUCCESS` is used all over the code base and make sure that the new `enum` value is handled properly.